# Jquery css 'display:block' not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am attempting to create a simple validation function for my contact form. 
[Click here](http://dev.steljes.com/collabor8) At the moment, once details are submitted the form keeps `display:none` even when entries are incorrect. I have tried to target the form `id` Which doesn't seem to be working either.

below is a snippet of my function

```
 var form = $('#ajax-contact');
 var formMessages = $('#form-messages');



  form.validate();
  $(form).submit(function(e) {

      if ($('#ajax-contact').valid()) {

        $('#ajax-contact').validate({
            rules: {
              name: {
                rangelength: [2, 40],
              },
              email: {
                rangelength: [2, 40],
                email: true,
                required: true
              },
              errorClass: "error",
              highlight: function (input) {
                $(input).closet('.required').removeClass('has-success').addClass('has-error');
              }
            }
        })

      } else {
        $("#ajax-contact").css({'display:block'});
        console.log('not working');
      }
  })
```

Comment: [css link](http://api.jquery.com/css/) you can't use an array when update the style

Comment: You've also misspelt `closest` as `closet`.

Comment: please read the docs for the validation plugin again. you are setting up validation rules in the 'submit' event handler. this has to be done initially instead. if you do that you have to use an 'invalid' handler if you want to respond to an invalid form since the validation framework will suppress form submit's if the form is invalid.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`.css` should be used this way:

```
$("#ajax-contact").css('display','block');
```

and if you have multiple `.css` to be set then you can go with

```
$("#ajax-contact").css({'display':'block','position':'relative'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `css({display: "block"})` as it takes an object as options. Not an array